# python finding high value among slices of array

Tags: python, numpy

Below are snippets of code that is giving me some problems.  what i am trying to do is find every occurrence of a 356 day high. To do this i am trying code similar to the one below, but getting an exception on the "for i" line: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

```
Quote = namedtuple("Quote", "Date Close Volume")

quotes = GetData() # arrray

    newHighs = []
    for i,q in range[365, len(quotes)]:  #<--Exception
        max = max(xrange[i-365, i].Close)  #<--i know this won't work, will fix when i get here
        if (q.Close > max):
            newHighs.append(i,q)
```

Any help on fixing this would be appreciated.  Also any tips on implementing this in an efficient manner (since quotes array currently has 17K elements) would also be nice.

Comment: I see an indentation after quotes = GedData()...  , is that correct ?

Comment: the line `max = max(...` is going to give you an issue after the first time through the loop as well, since you've just re-assigned the built-in function `max`

Comment: Please try and make this easier to understand! What is `quotes`? Is it a NumPy array? A Python list? Something else? Why have you included the line `Quote = namedtuple()` when it's not used in the rest of the code sample? Can you give us an example, simplified if necessary, of your input data and the output you want?

Comment: Also a bad idea to over-write the builtin `max`, especially since you're actually trying to use the `max` function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range` is a function that returns a generator (or list in python2). Thus, it must be called as a function `range(365, len(quotes))`, which will return all the numbers from 365 to len(quotes).

Square brackets imply indexing, like accessing items in a list. Since range is a function, not a list, it throws an exception when you try to access it.

Comment: thank you. i am new to python...how can i achieve what i'm trying to do then? can an array be 'sliced' using an offset?

Comment: Absolutely. To get a subset of an array, you can use array[start:stop] syntax.

Answer (score 3):

"Range" is a function. This means you use circle brackets, not square ones. This is the same deal with "xrange" in the line below. I understand why you'd think to use the square brackets, but what "range" does is create the list using those arguments. So it's not the same as when you want elements m to n of a list.